# Which Ports manager to use on FreeBSD? (8.0 and above)

Tags: freebsd, package-management, freebsd-ports

There is no clear answer which one to use on the net. Tried searching but couldn't dig up anything useful. Also, the user manual mentions them altogether, won't list the advantages/disadvantages, which is better, etc.

Sadly the webpages are also mostly dead. I'd like to ask the community which one to use.
The ones I found:
http://dougbarton.us/portmaster.html
http://portmanager.sourceforge.net/
http://wiki.freebsd.org/portupgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out people both use PortMaster and Portupgrade. Sad thing ports were broken when I tried my first upgrade. :}

Answer (score 1):

`portupgrade` is the former best choice, when `portmaster` was not existing. It still is a more complete product, but I find that `portmaster` is nowadays complete enough with the most used features (as in "I didn't need portugprade in the last few months at all") and, being a shell script, has no dependencies and is a breeze to install.

Comment: nowadays it's usual to use `pkg install` for binary packages, too.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use portupgrade, but after portmaster had been out for a while I switched over and didn't look back: it just seems to Do The Right Thing as far as I'm concerned: it collects all the messages (pkg-message) that ports like to display into a single list to display at the end, and it does all the configuring of options up-front. From what I've read I believe a lot of other people prefer it too.